# Determinant (defined via permutation) and invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $R$ is a commutative ring with unity and $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix over $R$. If the determinant $|A|$ of $A$ is defined as $$|A|:=\sum_{\pi\in S_n}\text{sgn}(\pi)a_{1, \pi(1)}\cdots a_{n,\pi(n)},$$ where $S_n$ is the permutation group of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. How does one prove that $A$ is invertible iff its determinant is a unit in $R$?
Please help me to prove this pure via permutation if possible.

Comment: Determinant non-invertible => matrix non-invertible is pretty straightforward : if A invertible,  $det A * det A^{-1} = 1$

Comment: for the other way, can’t you use the comatrix as an inverse ?

Comment: Yes, it is a proof for one direction. But how to prove for another direction?

Comment: does the cofactor matrix not work ? It works on fields, not sure it generalizes to rings

Comment: The formula $\operatorname{adj}(A)A=A\operatorname{adj}(A)=(\det A)I$ works [for all $A\in M_n(R)$ and any commutative ring $R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix).